# using text-overflow:ellipsis; only when reaching 3 lines in a div

Tags: javascript, ellipsis, css

this is my css snippet

```
.test{
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

what it does is..

```
the quick brown fo...
```

what i want is

```
the quick brown fox
jumps over the lazy
dog. the quick br...
```

is there anyway to do this with just CSS? or do i need to use javascript for this. If javascript is needed, anyone can teach me how? thanks!

**UPDATE**

i tried removing the `white-space: nowrap;` and added `overflow-y: hidden;` it gives me the 3 line layout but no ellipsis

```
.test{
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Not possible with just css... I use this plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/

Comment: i see, will try the plugin now..

Comment: Put ur code in fiddle and send ya..

Answer (score 7):

you could use the `dotdotdot` plugin http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/, it works fine for me.

pure css can work in some broswers, but it has many limits. Suppose you want `...` at the end of the line3.

```
.test{
   display: -webkit-box;
   height: 60px; 
   -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this one

```
.test { width: 150px; height: 60px; overflow-y: hidden; position: relative; }

.test:after { content: '...'; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```

Comment: The :after technique worked for me, but in my case I had to remove the "right: 0"