# javascript/angularjs cut string to fit in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

in my angularjs/ionic mobile application I have implemented a list of messages. Now I want to modify it, so that if the message text is wider than the div container it should cut the string and adds 3 dots.

My message list looks like this:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <ion-item can-swipe="true" class="item-icon-left item-icon-right">

          <i class="icon ion-email-unread"></i>

          <div class="row">
            <span class="col col-50">
              <h2>{{message.title}}</h2>
            </span>
            <span class="col col-50 content-right text-small">
              {{message.dateString}}
            </span>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <span class="col text-small">
              {{message.text}}
            </span>
          </div>

          <i class="icon ion-chevron-right"></i>

          <ion-option-button class="button-dark">
            More
          </ion-option-button>
          <ion-option-button class="button-assertive">
            Delete
          </ion-option-button>
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
```

How can I do this dynamically, so that it really depends on the width of the device/container?

Comment: You can add :after content with ... and overflow hidden

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't do that with JS.

Simply use CSS's `overflow` and `text-overflow` properties:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>1234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
```

Comment: This only works with a fixed width, which collides with flowing text in a responsive design

Comment: @dube: `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` works just fine on elements with a dynamic width. __[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hbzg3q7c/).__

Comment: Apologies for my short comment. Your sample works because the text is a single, big word. It works with real text too, if you add "white-space:nowrap". 
However, that's no fun with multi-line text (which was not asked for here). [Updated Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hbzg3q7c/2/)

Comment: Hm, in that case, [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229828/using-text-overflowellipsis-only-when-reaching-3-lines-in-a-div) can be of help, @dube.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this easily by using CSS and specifying a `width` for your content and adding a `text-overflow` style with the value of `elipsis`.

```css
#crop-text {
  /* essential */
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 160px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  /* for good looks */
  padding: 10px;
  
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="crop-text">Hello, this is a really long text string.</div>
```

This tutorial explains what you need to do. http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis